# How to do 301 redirects with folders & subfolders?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect all the old URLs on my site to new URLs, but am having issues. A given URL and its subfolders need redirecting to the same page.

For example, this is the first one:

> redirect 301 /panache/sports-bra/ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/sports-bra.html

This works ok. However there are these size sub-pages which need to redirect to the same location:

> redirect 301 /panache/sports-bra/30DD http://www.newdomain.co.uk/sports-bra.html
>
> redirect 301 /panache/sports-bra/30E http://www.newdomain.co.uk/sports-bra.html
>
> redirect 301 /panache/sports-bra/30F http://www.newdomain.co.uk/sports-bra.html

And these don't work, I end up at a location like the following:

> http://www.newdomain.co.uk/sports-bra.html30DD

See the way the last part of the path is appended to the url? I'm guessing it's because the second redirect is conflicting with the initial 301 redirect?

I have also tried using this rewrite rule but have had no luck. The site is Magento so I don't know if this has some effect? **mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.**

> RewriteRule ^panache/sports-bra/ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/sports-bra.html [R=301]

Any help mucha ppreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(panache/sports-bra/.*)$ /sports-bra.html [L,R=301,NC]
```